# link in SWF should open a new page, but doesn't

Tags: actionscript-3, hyperlink, flash

I have some images floating around in my SWF.
The SWF holds several buttons, linked to those pics etc.
The buttons have actions:

```
on(release) { getURL("http://domain.com/sub/folder/page.html/"); }
```

When clicking on the image I would like a new page to open in which the link is executed.
How come the current code isn't working?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!!

I needed to use "_blank" as the target:

```
on(release) { getURL("http://domain.com/sub/folder/page.html/","_blank"); }
```